# Regarding the HTML Label's "For" Property

Tags: html, label

Considering the following 2 lines of code (copied from w3schools.com > "HTML < label > for Attribute"):

```
  <label for="male">Male </label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" />
```

I am having trouble discovering the exact purpose of the above label's "for" property. As you can see it is currently set to "male" (to match the id of the input control).

All I have read so far is that the above code will 'associate' and 'bound' the label with the input control.
So my question is, what exactly does this mean?

What exactly are the results of associating the label to the input control? 
 Does the label and/or input have new behaviours as a result of this 'association'?

Comment: You guys work quick, thankyou for the many answers, I wish I could give you all a tick :)

Comment: @user This question was asked Jun 29 '10 at 16:53 where as your actual duplicate was asked Aug 25 '13 at 18:40.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

A `label` that is associated with a control via `for` will be clickable. Clicking it selects the control. Highly useful with radio/checkboxes in particular. It also has accessibility implications for screen readers for the visually impaired.

Comment: +1 you click the text and the bound <input> element will be selected

Comment: +1 good work, also valuable to note if you use <label `for`="">, `for` must map to the input element's `ID`, and not its name.

Comment: Worth noting that you can get the same behavior by enclosing the `input` tag within the `label` tag like so: http://jsfiddle.net/makeblake/9y86g/

Comment: Also worth noting that a for attribute with a hidden input type is not W3C valid.

Answer (score 9):

When you click on the ***label*** (Male), the radio will be checked something not possible if you are not using a label. A label is also useful when developing for small devices such as mobiles.

So, it is useful for:

- accessibility reasons
- smaller devices such as mobiles, etc
- useful in radio buttons and check boxes especially

Comment: Uh, it's `label`, not `lable`.

Comment: @ceejayoz: yes a typo, fixed, thanks

Comment: Is link's contents are changed? I didn't find information.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that linking a label to a form element allows you to assign the `label` an access key, which will bring the focus to the form element associated with it.

As others have mentioned it also allows you to click on the `label` and bring focus to the form element.

The for attribute alllows you to place the `label` and the element in semantically different areas of the html, and maintain association. (Like two tables, or two different divs).  If you're putting both of them together like in your example, it is also correct to enclose the form element in the label and forgo the `for` attribute

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe it acts as a form control or a check mechanism when filling a form on webpage, especially ones with radio buttons or check boxes.  By clicking on the label, it points the user directly to an area on the form where the right information should be typed.  For example, a "text."  Or, in a case where the user must choose from some options, such as true or false, or male or female.