# why do I need to bind checkbox with a label?

Tags: css, checkbox, label, for-attribute

I got a quick question here. Why do we always bind a checkbox id to the for-attribute in a label? Does it have any purpose? If so, can you please list it out? And also its technical advantage.

Thanks in advance,
Madhu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *always* have to bind a checkbox (or any input) id to a label.  What it does is allow you to click the label to trigger a click of the checkbox (or input).  This also works if the label element wraps the `<input>` without requiring id/for:

```
<label for="checkbox">Click checkbox</label> <input id="checkbox" type=checkbox>
<label>Click checkbox <input type=checkbox></label>
```

Comment: According to accessibility guidelines, you *always* have to provide a label that is programmatically determinable. But wrapping the `input` element inside `label` is sufficient for this. It’s just a bit unnatural.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela why is it unnatural?

Comment: An input control is not logically part of its label.

Comment: ExplosionPills and Jukka : thanks a lot for your response. These were the answers that i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does have a purpose. Basically it allows you to "click" it, it also has use for screen readers.

Answer: [Regarding the HTML Label's "For" Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142884/regarding-the-html-labels-for-property)